# HTML links in emails on Android

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

So, I've been trying to get this to work properly on Android, but for some reason, the mails being sent are not going out with the links. This works on iOS.

```
var emailDialog = Titanium.UI.createEmailDialog();

if (emailDialog.isSupported()) {
    emailDialog.subject = 'Sharing my app';
    emailDialog.messageBody = 'I want to share with you my app.<br/><br/>Download it to your mobile device to:<br/><br/>• Access cool stuff<br/>• Personalize stuff<br/>• Do even more stuff<br/>• Share content<br/><br/>Visit <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=testigtime&hl=en">Google Play Store</a> or the <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/en/genre/ios/">Apple App Store</a> to download My App for phone or tablet now.<br/><br/>Best,<br/>[Name]';
    emailDialog.html = true;
    emailDialog.open();
}
```

As you can see, there are two links. This properly pops up the mail dialog, and it even displays the texts Google Play Store and Apple App Store as blue links. Once I hit send and see how it went through, it appears to completeley remove the links. Can anyone help out?

Comment: See this link with same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588529/email-dialog-html-ignores-some-tags-titanium-moblie

Comment: Yeah found that. This is 5 years ago, and I don't know what alternatives we have.

Comment: Its totally up to the email client whether to display links or not-  just like for every other OS out there.  I don't know about the current state of the default email app or default gmail app, but there's nothing you can do to force it.  For that matter you can't force it on a PC either-  lots of people choose not to receive HTML email.  (I only whitelist certain people to be able to send html, because 99% of it is spam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems related to the Android email client you use as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8634263/4626813).

I'd suggest you install an alternative (bleeding edge) email app and see if that resolves it. Then we know for sure it's the default Android email client. If not, then it might be worth to create an Appcelerator JIRA ticket to have this looked into.

What Android version did you got this with?

Comment: Thanks Fokke. I tested with the Gmail client and it's working correctly. This bug is happening on both Inbox by Gmail as well as the Android default email client. I've tested this on Android 4.1, 4.4 and 5.0. The strange thing is that when it's in the compose email, the text actually displays like it contains a link (blue text), but when the mail is sent, it's sent without the anchor tag.